How to implement custom grouping in ListBox WPF?
Is it possible to implement 'custom' grouping for ListBox without using CollectionView and CollectionViewSource?
I apologize in advance for my English and if I haven't described the problem in enough detail.
I have a simple MVVM implementation with a collection that loads grouped objects. I also used DynamicData (https://dynamic-data.org/) for working with collections. Below is the entire application code:
public class ChatMessage
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Sender { get; set; }
    public long Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public bool Delivered { get; set; }
}

<Window
    x:Class="DynamicDataTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicDataTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ChatViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedMessages}">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="0,10,0,5"
                                FontSize="14"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Text="{Binding Key, StringFormat={}{0:dd MMMM yyyy}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public class ChatViewModel : AbstractNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SourceCache<ChatMessage, long> _sourceList = new SourceCache<ChatMessage, long>(m => m.Id);

    public ObservableCollectionExtended<GroupAdapter> GroupedMessages { get; }  = new ObservableCollectionExtended<GroupAdapter>();

    public ChatViewModel()
    {
        // Load test messages
        GetTestMessages();  

        _sourceList
            .Connect()
            .Group(msg => msg.Timestamp.Date)
            .Transform(group => new GroupAdapter(group))
            .Bind(GroupedMessages)
            .Subscribe();
    }

    private void GetTestMessages()
    {
        var messages = new[]
        {
            new ChatMessage { Id = 1, Sender = 1, Receiver = 2, Content = "Hi!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 2, Sender = 2, Receiver = 1, Content = "Hi, how are you ?", Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).AddHours(1) },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 3, Sender = 1, Receiver = 2, Content = "I'm fine!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 4, Sender = 2, Receiver = 1, Content = "Nice!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
        };

        foreach (var message in messages)
            _sourceList.AddOrUpdate(message);
    }
}

public class GroupAdapter : IGrouping<DateTime, ChatMessage>
{
    private readonly IGroup<ChatMessage, long, DateTime> _group;

    public GroupAdapter(IGroup<ChatMessage, long, DateTime> group)
    {
        _group = group;
    }

    public DateTime Key => _group.Key;

    public IEnumerator<ChatMessage> GetEnumerator() => _group.Cache.Items.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

Due to the memory leak issue when using CollectionView (https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6087?ysclid=m2eyff5ejh132836292), I have the following question: Is it possible to implement "custom" grouping for ListBox?
As seen above, I implemented the IGrouping interface in GroupAdapter, hoping it would help. However, I encountered the following problems:

The group header does not display.

If multiple objects belong to one group, only the first one is displayed.


Result:

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Re: "Custom" grouping. I use 2 ListBoxes (or ListViews; or DataGrids). The first points to a collection of "group" items. When the "selection changes" in the first, I query the "group's children"; and attach that result to the second ListBox. The 2 are now in synch, and all the children are shown (for that group).  If the "groups" are generated initially from the children, then there will always be a relationship (i.e. no groups without children). Performance has never been an issue.

@GerrySchmitz Thank you for the proposed solution, I really appreciate it! However, I'm not sure it will work for me because I'm aiming for a result similar to what is shown in this screenshot: Example

I think using a ListView (on the right) might prove more fruitful in this case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-items-in-a-listview-that-implements-a-gridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
